# Combining 2 dictionaries with common key

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have two dictionaries and need to combine the values of similar keys in them. Here's an example:

```
dict1 = {'key1':[value11,value12,value13] , 'key2':[value21,value22,value23]}
dict2 = {'key1':[value14,value15] , 'key2':[value24,value25]}
```

I used :

```
dict3 = {}
for key in (dict1.viewkeys() | dict2.keys()):
    if key in dict1: dict3.setdefault(key, []).append(dict1[key])
    if key in dict2: dict3.setdefault(key, []).append(dict2[key])
```

which gives me:

```
dict3 = {'key1':[[value11,value12,value13],[value14,value15]] , 'key2':[[value21,value22,value23],[value24,value25]]}
```

What I want is a simple one like:

**Desired output** :

```
 dict3 = {'key1':[value11,value12,value13,value14,value15] , 'key2':[value21,value22,value23,value24,value25]}
```

Comment: probably a simple `print {k:dict1.get(k, []) + dict2.get(k, []) for k in set(dict1.keys() + dict2.keys())}` would do

Comment: do you still want the averages?

Comment: Yes , but others told me to ask it as a separate question

Comment: lol and when you did you were asked to edit this question, I had an answer to the question you deleted

Comment: [Here is the other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25408370/combine-dictionaries-with-aggregate-values-for-similar-keys-python).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is to modify `append` to `extend` which will then add the elements of the list rather than adding the list itself. See the [`list` docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) for more details on the difference between `append` and `extend`.

```
dict1 = {'key1':['value11','value12','value13'] , 'key2':['value21','value22','value23']}
dict2 = {'key1':['value14','value15'] , 'key2':['value24','value25']}

dict3 = {}
for key in set().union(dict1, dict2):
    if key in dict1: dict3.setdefault(key, []).extend(dict1[key])
    if key in dict2: dict3.setdefault(key, []).extend(dict2[key])

print(dict3)
# {'key2': ['value21', 'value22', 'value23', 'value24', 'value25'], 'key1': ['value11', 'value12', 'value13', 'value14', 'value15']}
```

Alternatively you could use a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) with the default set to `list` as shown below.

```
from collections import defaultdict
dict3 = defaultdict(list)

for key in set().union(dict1, dict2):
  for dic in [dict1, dict2]:
    if key in dic:
      dict3[key] += dic[key]
```

Comment: what does defaultdict(list) do??

Comment: `defaultdict(list)` is similar to using `setdefault` in your example. Basically if the key isn't already in `dict3` then it will set the value as default `[]`. This way is just a bit neater (IMHO).

Comment: I dislike the except KeyError: pass − It's a bad management of Exceptions.

Comment: @Ffisegydd you can use a condition (if key in dic) instead of an Exception management with a pass statement.

Comment: Plus, I tried to test your answer and (dict1.keys() | dict2.keys()) returns an error in python 2.7

Comment: @QuentinTHEURET whilst I disagree with you I've modified it as it is probably more readable for people who aren't too versed in `try...except...` loops. And yes I changed it to `keys` for Python 3.4 (which is what I used).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a generic method on which you can pass as many dict as you want as parameter.

```
>>> def mix_dict(*args):
       res = {}
       for d in args:
           if not isinstance(d, dict):
               continue
           for k, v in d.iteritems():
               res.setdefault(k, [])
               if isinstance(v, list):
                   res[k].extend(v)
               else:
                   res[k].append(v)
       return res
>>> dict1 = {'key1':['value11','value12','value13'] , 'key2':['value21','value22','value23']}
>>> dict2 = {'key1':['value14','value15'] , 'key2':['value24','value25']}
>>> dict3 = mix_dict(dict1, dict2)
>>> print dict3
... {'key1': ['value11', 'value12', 'value13', 'value14', 'value15'],
     'key2': ['value21', 'value22', 'value23', 'value24', 'value25']}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it much simpler but if you want to use your code just change `append` to `extend`

```
dict1 = {'key1':['value11','value12','value13'] , 'key2':['value21','value22','value23']}
dict2 = {'key1':['value14','value15'] , 'key2':['value24','value25']}

dict3 = {}
for key in (dict1.viewkeys() | dict2.keys()):
    if key in dict1: dict3.setdefault(key, []).extend(dict1[key])
    if key in dict2: dict3.setdefault(key, []).extend(dict2[key])

print dict3
```

output:

```
{'key2': ['value21', 'value22', 'value23', 'value24', 'value25'], 'key1': ['value11', 'value12', 'value13', 'value14', 'value15']}
```

You can read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/252703/1982962) about the difference ov append to extend

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to do this.

You can support merging N dicts of lists into a single dict of lists with this function:

```
def mergeDoLs(*dicts):
    def flatten(LoL):
        return [e for l in LoL for e in l]

    rtr={k:[] for k in set(flatten(d.keys() for d in dicts))}
    for k, v in flatten(d.items() for d in dicts):
        rtr[k].extend(v)
    return rtr
```

To use:

```
>>> dict1 = {'key1':['value11','value12','value13'] , 'key2':['value21','value22','value23'], 'key3':[1]}
>>> dict2 = {'key1':['value14','value15'] , 'key2':['value24','value25']}
>>> dict3 = {'key3':[2]}
>>> mergeDoLs(dict1, dict2, dict3) 
{'key3': [1, 2], 'key2': ['value21', 'value22', 'value23', 'value24', 'value25'], 'key1': ['value11', 'value12', 'value13', 'value14', 'value15']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use dict.update() to merge two dictionaries keys: `dict1['key1'].update(dict2['key1'])`