# How to iterate through the dictionaries of a string representation of a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary

In such an example:

```
"[{'id' : 18, 'name' : 'Rick'}, {'id' : 19, 'name' : 'Luke'}]"
```

I am working with a `str` representation of a `list` of `dict`s. How can I iterate through the list to return a new list of all the "id's" in the dictionaries?

The desired result:

```
[18, 19]
```

EDIT:
I have tried already to cast the string into a list with `ast.literal_eval(foolist)` and iterated through the items in the list. However, when I do this, it iterates through the characters in `foolist` starting with `"{"` then `"'"`.

Comment: Well, start by converting it from a string to a real list of dicts.

Comment: Try `[d['id'] for d in eval(s)]`. `eval` helps you to convert the string into a list.

Comment: `literal_eval`, please.

Comment: Can you show the code you wrote using `ast.literal_eval`? It sounds like you didn't use it properly, so you were still iterating over the original string.

Comment: @Zhiya works brilliantly! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in several comments:

```
import ast


foolist = "[{'id' : 18, 'name' : 'Rick'}, {'id' : 19, 'name' : 'Luke'}]"
[d["id"] for d in ast.literal_eval(foolist)]
# [18, 19]
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this code would serve your purpose

```
a = "[{'id' : 18, 'name' : 'Rick'}, {'id' : 19, 'name' : 'Luke'}]"

a = a.split(',')
output = []
for data in a:
    data = data.replace('[', '').replace('{','').replace(']','').replace('}','').replace(' ','')
    if eval(data.split(':')[0]) == 'id':
        output.append(data.split(':')[1])
print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have adapted a previous answer on [Combining 2 dictionaries with common key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25406281/9209546).

```
def mergeDoLs(*dicts):
    def flatten(LoL):
        return [e for l in LoL for e in l]
    rtr= {k: [] for k in set(flatten(d for d in dicts))}
    for k, v in flatten(d.items() for d in dicts):
        rtr[k].append(v)
    return rtr

d_str = "[{'id' : 18, 'name' : 'Rick'}, {'id' : 19, 'name' : 'Luke'}]"
d = mergeDoLs(*eval(d_str))
d['id']

# output
# d = {'id': [18, 19], 'name': ['Rick', 'Luke']}
# d['id'] = [18, 19]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON built-in library.

```
import json

raw_string = "[{'id' : 18, 'name' : 'Rick'}, {'id' : 19, 'name' : 'Luke'}]"
json_string = raw_string.replace('\'', '"') #converting NON-JSON string to JSON string


my_dictionary = dict()
my_dictionary = json.loads(json_string)

ids = []

for item in my_dictionary:
    ids.append(int(item['id']))

print(ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

**I tried this:-**

```
import json

a = "[{'id' : 18, 'name' : 'Rick'}, {'id' : 19, 'name' : 'Luke'}]"
final_list = []
a = a.replace("'",'"')
b = '{"chck":'+a+"}"
b = json.loads(b)
for i in b.values():
    for j in i:
        final_list.append(j['id'])
print (final_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this method :

```
import ast

data="[{'id' : 18, 'name' : 'Rick'}, {'id' : 19, 'name' : 'Luke'}]"


print(list(map(lambda x:x['id'],ast.literal_eval(data))))
```

output:

```
[18, 19]
```