# Compare dicts and merge them. No overwrite and no duplicate values

Tags: python, dictionary

I made a mistake in my question here (wrong requested input and expected output):
[Comparing dicts, updating NOT overwriting values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58605665/comparing-dicts-updating-not-overwriting-values)

I am **not** looking for this solution:
[Combining 2 dictionaries with common key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25405861/combining-2-dictionaries-with-common-key)
So this question is **not** a duplicate

Problem statement:

requested input:

```
d1 = {'a': ['a'], 'b': ['b', 'c']}
d2 = {'b': ['c', 'd'], 'c': ['e','f']}
```

expected output (I don't care about the order of the keys / values!):

```
new_dict = {'a': ['a'], 'b': ['b', 'c', 'd'], 'c': ['e', 'f']}
```

The solution in [Combining 2 dictionaries with common key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25405861/combining-2-dictionaries-with-common-key)
gives following output:

```
new_dict = {'a': ['a'], 'b': ['b', 'c', 'c', 'd'], 'c': ['e', 'f']}
```

I don't want the duplicates to be stored.

My solution (it **works** but it is not so efficient):

```
unique_vals = []
new_dict = {}
for key in list(d1.keys())+list(d2.keys()) :
    unique_vals = []
    try:
        for val in d1[key]:
            try:
                for val1 in d2[key]:
                    if(val1 == val) and (val1 not in unique_vals):
                        unique_vals.append(val)
            except:
                continue
    except:        
        new_dict[key] = unique_vals
    new_dict[key] = unique_vals


for key in d1.keys():
    for val in d1[key]:
        if val not in new_dict[key]:
            new_dict[key].append(val)
for key in d2.keys():
    for val in d2[key]:
        if val not in new_dict[key]:
            new_dict[key].append(val)
```

Comment: This is python 3.5?

Comment: This is python 3.7

Comment: Just use sets `{'a','b'}` instead of lists. The duplicate element will get deleted from set. However they are unordered

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is how I would go about it:

```
d1 = {'a': ['a'], 'b': ['b', 'c']}
d2 = {'b': ['c', 'd'], 'c': ['e','f']}
dd1 = {**d1, **d2}
dd2 = {**d2, **d1}
{k:list(set(dd1[k]).union(set(dd2[k]))) for k in dd1}
```

Produces the desired result.

Answer (score 6):

I suggest using a default dictionary collection with a set as a default value.
It guarantees that all values will be unique and makes the code cleaner.

Talking about efficiecy it's O(n^2) by time.

```py
   from collections import defaultdict


   d1 = {'a': ['a'], 'b': ['b', 'c']}
   d2 = {'b': ['c', 'd'], 'c': ['e','f']}

   new_dict = defaultdict(set)

   for k, v in d1.items():
       new_dict[k] = new_dict[k].union(set(v))

   for k, v in d2.items():
       new_dict[k] = new_dict[k].union(set(v))
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this code. You can remove deep copy if modifications in the initial array are fine for you.

```
import copy


def merge(left, right):
    res = copy.deepcopy(left)

    for k, v in right.items():
        res[k] = list(set(res[k]).union(v)) if k in res else v

    return res
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple if statement if you don't want to use a Set.

```py
d3 = dict(d2)
for k,v in d1.items():
    if k not in d3:
        d3[k] = v
    else:
        for n in d1[k]:
            if n not in d3[k]:
                d3[k].append(n)
```